# É necessário colocar as importações do meu código na pergunta?

Tags: debate, suporte, formatação

Muitas linguagens usam importação, como por exemplo java, e é comum os códigos relacionados ao problema ter várias linhas que importam classes utilizadas no mesmo, uma MainActivity que não faz nada no android studio tem pelo menos 2 imports e o package:

```
package com.example.helloworld;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
```

Quando uma aplicação ter algum erro que o desenvolvedor não consegue resolver sozinho, vai ter pelo menos uns 10 imports

Talvez em algum caso específico seja necessário colocar essas linhas, mas em geral, é necessário colocar as importações do meu código na pergunta?

**Observação:** a pergunta usa como o exemplo o java no android porque é a linguagem que mais uso que necessita de várias importações, mas gostaria de uma resposta em geral, fora as linguagens HTML, CSS e JavaScript, quando é usado Snippet (nesse caso é necessário a importação das bibliotecas/frameworks para executar corretamente)

Comment: Sim, eu acho necessário. Como Java/JavaScript possuem muitas bibliotecas, acho necessário adicionar os *import* ou ao menos citá-los. Se um usuário postar um código com `AsyncHttpClient`, como saberei que é [**AsyncHttpClient/async-http-client**](https://github.com/AsyncHttpClient/async-http-client) e não [**loopj/android-async-http**](https://github.com/loopj/android-async-http)? Quando ele deixa explicito (via *import* ou citação) fica mais fácil para a pessoa buscar a documentação e fazer alguns testes — caso seja necessário.

Comment: 10 imports não é nada perto do tamanho do stack trace que você provavelmente vai precisar postar se a pergunta for de java :D

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/168101/132 e https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/168082/como-resolver-este-java-lang-illegalargumentexception-unknown-entity-ao-rodar/168101#comment346098_168082

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Eu acho conveniente, por uma série de razões:

- Como disse o Valdeir em comment: *"Se um usuário postar um código com AsyncHttpClient, como saberei que é AsyncHttpClient/async-http-client e não loopj/android-async-http? Quando ele deixa explicito (via import ou citação) fica mais fácil para a pessoa buscar a documentação e fazer alguns testes — caso seja necessário"*.
- Os imports ajudam um terceiro que queira responder e não tenha tanta familiaridade com a linguagem. Muitas vezes um algoritmo tem um erro evidente que qualquer programador mediano pode resolver rapidamente, mas sem os imports quem não é familiar com a linguagem se complica para fazer um [IDEONE](http://ideone.com) ou similar, pois é obrigado a ficar estudando o "ecossistema" da linguagem para poder fazer um simples teste, mesmo já estando convencido de onde está o erro.
- A ordem dos imports podem fazer diferença em algumas linguagens (JS, por exemplo) quando se tratam de interdependências. Muitas vezes vamos responder pro usuário que faltou a biblioteca X, e ele pode insistir que já adicionou... mas esquecemos que pode estar na ordem errada.

Em tempo: vale notar que sempre depende do contexto. Tem trechos de código que não dependem de nada disso. Se tem consciência de que realmente o problema não tem nada a ver com isso, e o [MCVE](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) não depende de imports, passa a ser informação espúria.

## Simplificando:

Sempre que ficar em dúvida, faça um **[Exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)** do problema, que já vai saber quando e quais imports por na pergunta.

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/168101/132 e https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/168082/como-resolver-este-java-lang-illegalargumentexception-unknown-entity-ao-rodar/168101#comment346098_168082

Comment: Já teve um caso uma vez onde tive que reverter algumas edições que fiz numa pergunta porque imaginei que o OP estava falando de uma determinada API, quando na verdade era de uma outra API bem diferente que tinha algumas classes com o mesmo nome. Se os imports estivessem na pergunta, eu não teria feito essa confusão. Entretanto, não encontrei o link.

Comment: E há o caso também onde o OP utiliza uma biblioteca não-padrão, mas ele se esquece de dizer isso na pergunta. Com os imports completos, fica bem mais fácil de localizar essas bibliotecas. Já vi algumas perguntas desse tipo, onde alguns usuários chegam a dar votos de fechamento até aparecer alguém que por acaso teve a sacada que ele estava usando determinada biblioteca e salvar a pergunta com algumas edições (em alguns casos, esse alguém foi eu, mas já vi alguns outros usuários fazendo isso). No entanto, na maioria desses casos, a pergunta acaba sendo fechada por causa de um problema simples.